# SQL string concatenation based on field value

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am wondering if there is a straightforward way of concatenating a string based on the value of a field directly in SQL.  I know it would be preferable to do in an application, but in this instance, I am only able to use SQL.  For example, the following table:

```
Labels | Qty | LabelQty | OutputString
-------+-----+----------+--------------
     1 |  30 |       30 | NULL
     2 |  60 |       30 | NULL
     2 | 120 |       60 | NULL
```

I would like to end up with the OutputString like so:

```
Labels | Qty | LabelQty | OutputString
-------+-----+----------+--------------
     1 |  30 |       30 | 30|
     2 |  60 |       30 | 30|30|
     2 | 120 |       60 | 60|60|
```

I know this is very easy to do in C# or VB, but I am having a hard time thinking about how to accomplish this in straight SQL.  Would I need to use a cursor and do each row one at a time?  Unfortunately, I can't just use the string multiplier like in Ruby, such as:

```
SELECT (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LabelQty) + '|') * Labels
```

Any pointers are much appreciated.

Comment: what is the logic behind the output of the outputstring?

Comment: You have to tell us how you arrive at the contents of output string?  Do you want the LabelQty field repeated the number of times as Labels contains with `|` between?

Comment: Repeating the LabelQty number of Labels times?

Comment: Correct, as the bottom `SELECT` indicates.  Repeat the `LabelQty` field `Labels` number of times.

Comment: dub, the select at the bottom DOES NOT indicate that since `*` is not a valid operator for a string and this would result in a syntax error.  Better to use English for this requirement.

Comment: I was trying to show what the query would look like if I _could_ use the string multiplication as in Ruby.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: ah Ruby -- that explains a lot.  It is funny because you say `C#, VB` right above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `REPLICATE()` function:

```
select replicate(cast(LabelQty as varchar(100)) + '|', Labels)
from mytable_1
```

Comment: Wow, where has `REPLICATE()` been all my life!  This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: @dubstylee - `REPLICATE()` has been dating your twin brother.

Comment: 1+ for too fast answering. I withdraw my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
SELECT REPLICATE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LabelQty ) + '|',Labels )
```

Answer (score -2):

While you haven't described how to produce output string, but I think that this can be done with `case` expression:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

And sample from that article:

```
SELECT   ProductNumber, Name, "Price Range" = 
      CASE 
         WHEN ListPrice =  0 THEN 'Mfg item - not for resale'
         WHEN ListPrice < 50 THEN 'Under $50'
         WHEN ListPrice >= 50 and ListPrice < 250 THEN 'Under $250'
         WHEN ListPrice >= 250 and ListPrice < 1000 THEN 'Under $1000'
         ELSE 'Over $1000'
      END
FROM Production.Product
ORDER BY ProductNumber ;
```

Comment: No it seems clear he wants the Label repeated as many times as the Labels column.

Comment: @Vitaliy this is not what he pretended, not an answer.